# How to prevent component created from an array from re-rendering whenever the array is changed but the key is not?

Tags: reactjs

```
      <div className="app">
        {[1, 2].map((i) => {
          return <Test key={i} />;
        })}
      </div>
```

The goal is such that if the array is changed to `[2, 3]`, then the `Test` component that held the `key=2` should not re-render. That's because the key didn't change:

```
      <div className="app">
        {[2, 3].map((i) => {
          return <Test key={i} />;
        })}
      </div>
```

Is the above requirement possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible using [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo). It shouldn't rerender if the props are the same.

```js
// Where you define Test for example
const MemoizedTest = React.memo(Test);

...

// Inside your render function
<div className="app">
  {[1, 2].map((i) => {
    return <MemoizedTest key={i} />;
  })}
</div>
```